# Display sale badge on PLP

Tags: magento2, category, special-price

I am trying to display a 'Sale' badge on product category pages if the products have a special price. Though the isn't rendering anything.

```
<?php if (_$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue()): ?>
                        <div class="product-abs-top w-100">
                          <div class="tags-wrapper">
                              <div class="tag sale">Sale</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      <?php elseif ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('badge')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)): ?>
                        <div class="product-abs-top w-100">
                          <div class="tags-wrapper">
                              <div class="tag <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ str_replace(' ', '_',strtolower($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('badge')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product))) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('badge')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You have typo in your code:

```
<?php if (_$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue()): ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php if ($_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue()):
```

See **_$product**

Comment: FML cannot believe I didn't spot that. Thanks

Comment: Welcome @Paul :)